# log text parsing in linux

Tags: linux, text-parsing

I need to select a text from the log and store the field has a column to the new file.

For example below is the log format

```
[Mon Dec 07] [error] [client 10.0.0.65] [id "981004"] [file "sample"] [line "84"] [hostname "test"] [uri "/login"] [unique_id "VmVddAo"]
[Mon Dec 07] [error] [client 10.0.0.65] [file "sample"] [line "47"] [id "960015"] [rev "1"] [msg "Request Missing an Accept Header"] [severity "NOTICE"][ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "MISSING_HEADER_ACCEPT"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-21"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A7"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [hostname "test"] [uri "/home"] [unique_id "VmVddQo"]
```

Want to print the output like below

```
[Mon Dec 07] [id "981004"] [uri "/login"]
[Mon Dec 07] [id "960015"] [uri "/home"]
```

i have used awk to print as column wise

```
grep "Mon Dec 07" filename | sed '/\[[a-zA-Z]/\t&/g' | awk -F'\t' '{print $5}'

But i got the below output 

[id "981004"]
[file "sample"]

Because the column are found on different places, for example

[id "981004"] in the 4th column
[id "960015"] in the 6th column
```

How to get the value using like, the id as key and inside the double quotes is value for that key. After selecting  all the values it has to be stored in a new file(csv) as a  column.

Thanks vrs & Mirosław Zalewski

```
#!/bin/bash

search=$1
log=$2
regexp="s/(\[$search[^]]*\]).+(\[id[^]]*\]).+(\[uri[^]]*\]).+/\1 \2 \3/p"
sed -rn "$regexp" $2
```

&

```
perl -n -e '$,=" "; @groups = $_ =~ m/(\[.*?\]).*(\[(?:id|uri).*?\]).*((?-2)).*/ ; print @groups, "\n"' /path/to/log/file.log
```

both worked...

Comment: Using what language/tool/software? Where's your example? When you tried something, what happened? Which errors are you trying to solve?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See my revised answer for code that will be able to (almost) do what you requested in last edit. But seriously, you need a parser for that file format. I believe that asking people here to write one falls outside of scope of this website. But we can help with specific issues you will encounter along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

search=$1
log=$2
regexp="s/(\[$search[^]]*\]).+(\[id[^]]*\]).+(\[uri[^]]*\]).+/\1 \2 \3/p"
sed -rn "$regexp" $2
```

You can save this program to a file (say, `script.sh`), make it executable (`chmod +x script.sh`) and run `$ ./script.sh "Mon Dec 07" log.txt`

This is what the script does:

1. Assigns the first argument to the script to variable `$search` (text you want to match lines against), second one to variable `$log` (name of a log file)
2. Creates a regular expression for `sed`

   - `(...)` means grouping
   - `\[some text\]` means `some text` inside square brakets (they are escaped with baclslashes)
   - `[^...]`means any character but `...`, i.e. `[^]]` means any character but closing square bracket (that's needed for regex termination)
   - `.+` means any positive number of any characters
   - `\1` means that we need to use text from the first group (see the first bullet)
   - `sed`'s options `-rn` mean suppress default printing of each line and usage of extended regular expressions respectively
3. Use the regular expression with sed on your log file `log.txt`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, sure it helps.. But when i add [msg or [severity its not showing anything.. Do i have to customize the line.. Please suggest...

Comment: @user5712316 Just add a regexp for the needed item, where it's expected to be in the input string (say, between `id` and `uri`). But don't forget about adding grouping reference like `\4`! So this works well for `[msg ...]`: `regexp="s/(\[$search[^]]*\]).+(\[id[^]]*\]).+(\[msg[^]]*\]).+(\[uri[^]]*\]).+/\1 \2 \3 \4/p"`

Comment: it worked, for unique_id how to define in regexp.. underscore is there in the text.. can i define normally..

Comment: @Sasee well, sure you can. You don't even need to escape an underscore character. So the regexp catching `id`, `msg`, `uri` and `unique_id` will look like this: regexp="s/(\[$search[^]]*\]).+(\[id[^]]*\]).+(\[msg[^]]*\]).+(\[uri[^]]*\]).+(\[unique[^]]*\]).*/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5/p"
So now that you see the pattern, you may incorporate any other field to be catched by sed that you need.

Comment: @Sasee If you find my answer and comments helpful and solving your question, please consider accepting my answer and/or upvoting. That will show other people that this solution is working.

Answer (score 1):

This is quick and dirty one-line solution in perl:

```
perl -n -e '$,=" "; @groups = $_ =~ m/(\[.*?\]).*(\[(?:id|uri).*?\]).*((?-2)).*/ ; print @groups, "\n"' /path/to/log/file.log
```

This one assumes that first field contains date. It does not require any particular order of `id` and `uri` fields, but will print them in order they appear in file.

---

Another, more flexible, a little less dirty and many-lines solution in perl:

```
%seeked = map { $_ => 1 } qw(id uri unique_id severity msg);

while (<>) {
    my $string = $_;
    my $closing = 1;
    while ( $closing != -1 ) {
            $closing = index($string, "]");
            $field = substr($string, 0, $closing+1);
            $field =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
            $string = substr($string, $closing + 1);

            my @content = split(/ /, $field, 4);

            if (scalar @content == 3 and $field !~ m/"/) {
                    print $field . " ";
                    next;
            }

            if ($seeked{ substr($content[0], 1) }) {
                    print $field . " ";
            }
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

To use it, copy that code, paste it in file and save it as `whatever.pl`. Then, in shell, type:

```
perl /path/to/whatever.pl /path/to/log/file.log
```

In first line of code, inside parentheses right after `qw`, you declare fields you want to have printed. Modify that line if you want other fields or you don't want some of these fields.

This solution still can't print fields in pre-specified order and it can't print some string in place of missing optional field. You would need a parser for that - first put fields in some data structure and then, at end of line, print fields that were detected.

Additionally, "date-recognizing" code is Very Wrong™. It checks if field contains exactly two spaces and it does not contain double quote character. If it matches both of these conditions, it assumes the field is date and prints it. The correct solution would check if string represents valid date. This can be done by [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.52/lib/Date/Manip.pod) CPAN
module, but it needs to be installed separately.

---

If you want to print arbitrary fields in arbitrary order, you would need to write custom (?) parser for this file format. This shouldn't be too hard, but there are some pitfalls to look for:

- date field has implicit key
- type field has implicit key
- at least "client" field does not quote value
- many fields are optional
- some field can occur multiple times (at least "tag")

I don't think that CSV would be suitable format for that kind of data. It is best for two-dimensional data structures. Because your data has optional fields and fields that store lists, something more flexible - like XML or JSON - would be better.

On a side note, it seems that whoever writes these logs thought that it will be easy to read them. I would recommend checking up vendor documentation/support to see if they had any particular solution in mind.